# EF 5 Filtering on any column - Extension method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5, extension-methods

I'm developing a CRM type application, and one of the features I'm implementing is to be able to view a grid of data, and then use a single text box to filter values from any of the columns. I've come up with a pretty ugly solution (note that this method also orders the data using Dynamic Linq), however I'd like it to be more "generic", possibly using reflection so I can just call a WithFiltering extension method and provide the extension method the filter term. This is what I have so far:

```
public List<PersonModel> GetPeople(int owningOrganisationID, int skip, int records, out int totalCount, Ordering orderByDirection, string filter, string orderBy = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
            orderBy = "PersonID";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            filter = filter.ToLower();

            totalCount = Context.PeopleView.Where(p => p.OwningOrganisationID == owningOrganisationID &&
                p.City.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.CountryName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Forename.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.PersonTypeName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Postcode.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter)).Count();

            return Context.PeopleView.Where(p => p.OwningOrganisationID == owningOrganisationID &&
                p.City.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.CountryName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Forename.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.PersonTypeName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Postcode.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || p.Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter))
                    .OrderBy(orderBy + " " + orderByDirection.ToString())
                    .Skip(skip)
                    .Take(records)
                    .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            totalCount = Context.PeopleView.Where(p => p.OwningOrganisationID == owningOrganisationID).Count();

            return Context.PeopleView
                .Where(o => o.OwningOrganisationID == owningOrganisationID)
                .OrderBy(orderBy + " " + orderByDirection.ToString())
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(records)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

This not only looks pretty bad, but it's prone to errors and I'll be using the same kind of code on several different entities (PersonModel, OrganizationModel, DocumentModel etc...)

Just wondering if anyone has any better ideas for cleaner code?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED with a more correct solution to your problem**

Without using reflection, you could use the following pattern:

1. define a `IFilterable` class with a `FilterClause(string filter)` method
2. Implement the `IFilterable` class on your entities (`PersonModel`, `OrganizationModel`, etc.)
3. Write an extension for `IFilterable` objects that will apply your filtering
4. Use this extension when querying for data

So basically for each entity where you want to apply the same filtering you can implement `IFilterable` and define *which* properties and *how* these properties will be used for filtering.

Here is some code that illustrates the above concepts. First, define `IFilterable` and implement it on your entities classes (`PersonModel`, `OrganizationModel`, etc.)

```
/// <summary>
/// Specifies that the class can be filterable
/// </summary>
interface IFilterable {
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the way the filtering will occur
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool FilterClause(string filter);
}

//partial class definition for PersonModel
public partial class PersonModel: IFilterable{
    //entity properties (normaly these are generated by EF)
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwningOrganisationID { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string PersonTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //Implementation of IFiltrable 
    public bool FilterClause(string filter) {
        return City.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || CountryName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || Forename.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || PersonTypeName.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || Postcode.ToLower().Contains(filter)
                || Surname.ToLower().Contains(filter);
    }
}

//partial class definition for OrganizationModel
public partial class OrganizationModel: IFilterable{        

    //Implementation of IFiltrable 
    public bool FilterClause(string filter) {
        //replace 'true' with code that will apply filtering for the OrganizationModel class
        return  true;
    }
}
```

Now define an extenstion on the `IQueryable` object that will apply the filtering on objects that implement 'IFilterable'

```
static class FilterableEntensions{
    /// <summary>
    /// Filters a IFilterable enumeration
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <param name="filter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IQueryable<T> WithFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string filter)  where T: IFilterable  {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) {
            //filter is empty, return original query
            return query;
        }
        else {
            //apply the filter
            return query.Where(x => x.FilterClause(filter));
        }
    }
}
```

With these definitions above, your `GetPeople` method can be rewritten (see below). It also queries first for the ids only to set the `totalCount` value, and only with the paged ids for the final query

```
public List<PersonModel> GetPeople(int owningOrganisationID, int skip, int records, out int totalCount, Ordering orderByDirection, string filter, string orderBy = "") {

        List<PersonModel> result = new List<PersonModel>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy)) {
            orderBy = "PersonID";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) {
            filter = filter.ToLower();
        }

        //use a first query to take only the ids of the data that match the filter.
        List<int> peopleViewIds = Context.PeopleView
            .Where(p => p.OwningOrganisationID == owningOrganisationID)
            .WithFiltering(filter) //use our extension here!!!
            .OrderBy(orderBy + " " + orderByDirection.ToString())
            .Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

        //set the 'out' parameter to the total count of the retrieved ids
        totalCount = peopleViewIds.Count;

        if (totalCount > 0) {
            //page the ids accordingly (the sorting of the ids was applied in the previous query)
            List<int> pagedPeopleViewIds = peopleViewIds.Skip(skip).Take(records).ToList();

            //use the paged ids to make a second query, this time only with the required ids. 
            //This should be really fast if you have PersonModel.Id is a PRIMARY KEY or you have an index attached on this column
            //Please note the reuse of the OrderBy, this will ensure the correct order on the paged result
            result = Context.PeopleView.Where(p => pagedPeopleViewIds.Contains(p.Id))
                .OrderBy(orderBy + " " + orderByDirection.ToString())                    
                .ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```